# a way to find out the change of a DataTable's column while set expression property

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

There is a datagridview in the form , this dgv's datasource is a datatable with 3 column . I set the expression property for one of these columns . Now what I want is : when the value of this column ( which expression property is set) changed , a msgbox appear .

Comment: Use the datatable rowchanged event

Comment: Thanks , but RowChanged event just give the info about row that changed, I want the column that changed.

Comment: Every column is in a row - the only way an expression column will change is if one of the columns used in the expression changes - check that.

Comment: You're right , but it's very important for me to catch the change of expression column , not the columns in the expression ... I used your solution before but work as well as I want..